# How to import react files with Package.json

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I'm a React Native developer, and when I need to use a resource such as CSS, Images or others I put create a package.json file in a folder, then I write

```
{"name":"@resource"}
```

then, when I need a component that is in that same folder, I only put this

```
import Resource from '@resource/file-name';
```

and now I'm able to use that component without typing

```
import Resource from '../../resource/file-name'
```

Now I'm developing a React.js web app, and I want to do the same, but I thing that the way I now from React Native it's not the same here or if this is an actual React feature.

I did try to do the same as in React Native, having in mind that are similar frameworks, but is not working, I watched some videos, search in docs but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way you import packages/assets depends on how/where the packages come from. If it's a package that you installed through NPM such as `npm install <package_name>`, you can just do `import PackageName from "package_name"`.

If it's an asset such as an image, you can do `import ImageName from "../path_to_image.jpg"` and then use it by calling what you set as `ImageName` so for example a logo:

```js
import CompanyLogo from "../assets/logo.png"

<img src={CompanyLogo} alt="My company logo" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so, this is not like a package, ex. Let's suppose that I have a folder named Components, and in that folder I have another folder named Styles and then a file named Styles.css.
So, the way that you import that File is " import Resource from '../../Components/Styles/Style' " BUT if you create a file (package.json) in that folder named Components and there are 1 line of code in that file that are " {"name":"@resource"} " and now, if I want to use that file, I only need to do this " import Style from '@components/Styles/Styles'; ". ¿Is this possible?

Comment: ohhh, I gotcha, what you are referring to is called a path alias. You can read more about how to achieve that here:
https://dev.to/rfornal/create-path-aliases-in-react-2oid

Comment: Maaaaan thank you, that is exactly what I need thanks, and have a wonderful day.